# Problem sending html mails

Tags: emails

I´m using mime mail 6.x 1.1 module and simplenews 6.x 1.4. I create all my newsletter issues in html, and I choose to send in html. However, always the mails are received in Outlook, hotmail and gmail in plain text.

I am using those modules in anohter website and they work nice.

What must I check? Could be the host?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you check the email format in mimemail setting page ? and about the plain text. Did it come with html tags or just plain text.

Comment: Stone Vo, thanks, thanks and thanks. I have checked only plain text